# How does the shell/init create the stdio streams?

Tags: shell, file-descriptors, xv6

I am reading through the source of MIT's [xv6 OS](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public). This snippet comes at the beginning of `sh.c`:

```
// Ensure that three file descriptors are open.
while((fd = open("console", O_RDWR)) >= 0){
    if(fd >= 3){
      close(fd);
      break;
    }
}
```

I understand that this checks to see if *atleast* 3 file descriptors are open (presumably for stdin, stdout and stderr) by checking if the newly allocated file descriptor is above (or same as) 3.

1) How is it possible to `open` the same device multiple times from the same process and expect different file descriptors?

2) To understand this, I ran a similar snippet on my host machine (x86_64 Linux 4.6.0.1). The test program repeatedly `open`ed a text file in a loop to see if we can expect a different fd but it always produced the same file descriptor. From this, I concluded that `open`-ing a real file and a device (like `/dev/console`) somehow differs because the snippet from xv6 obviously works (tested in Qemu). What exactly is the difference?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    int cnt = 0;

    while ((fd = open("sample.txt", O_RDWR) > 0)) {
        if (cnt != 10) {
            cnt++;
            printf("File descriptor opened: %d\n", fd);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output on running it:

```
$ ./a.out
File descriptor opened: 1
File descriptor opened: 1
[snip]
File descriptor opened: 1
File descriptor opened: 1
```

**EDIT** Based on one of the answers, I ran `strace` on the executable and found that `open` [indeed](http://codepad.org/g1nvUB4y) returns multiple file descriptors but all of which are not printed, for some reason. Why would that be?

3) Somewhat unrelated, but isn't the convention of using stdio streams in fds 0-2 is just that - a convention? For example, if the initializing sequence alloted the input/output file descriptors to something else - would it somehow affect how its children do their I/O?

Comment: #2 doesn't sound right. Why not show the similar snippet of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually 3 questions.  Dispose of #2 immediately because the program is incorrect:

```
    while ((fd = open("sample.txt", O_RDWR) > 0)) {
```

you probably meant

```
    while ((fd = open("sample.txt", O_RDWR)) > 0) {
```

with the improperly-placed parentheses, you are only testing if `fd` is greater than zero (which since file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 are open, that is probably a good assumption).

For #1:  the [**`open`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) call (when successful) is defined to return distinct file descriptors.  If the device cannot be reopened, `open` would return `-1`.

For #3: sure, that's a *convention*, but also in the [POSIX *standard*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html).  Other systems have used other conventions, including having a fourth open stream for every program.

Further reading: [Using Your Aegis Environment (July 1988)](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/apollo/SR10/011021-A00_Using_Your_Aegis_Environment_Jul88.pdf)
See page 6-9, which says that Apollo Domain/OS had error **input** and **output*

Answer (score 1):

No, the code does not *check* descriptors, it actually opens them.
Giving no descriptors yet. Each open will give a new file descriptor, i.e. 0,1,2,3. The code breakes when reaching fd 3 leaving 0 to 2 open.

Each file descriptor is simply a pointer to some location in some file. Therefore it is no problem to have more than one descriptor for the same file.

If your test program gives the same fd for different open calls, there is a bug in it. Please show the code.

Yes, there is a strong convention on fd 0 to 2. If some code wants to print on stdout, it actually prints on fd 1. There is no way to "map" stdout to something else.

Answer (score 1):

1) If the system supports opening the same file from multiple processes at the same time, then why not allow one process to open at multiple times, too? Since file descriptors are inherited, you could end up with the same file twice in the same process anyway, i.e. if it's inherited once and once opened by the process itself. Checking what files the process has open and returning a reference to the earlier one would be extra work.

Also, then there's the question if different parts of the process using the same file simultaneously. Say a library uses some configuration file at the same time the main program uses it. The file descriptor is tied to the access mode and the position of the file pointer. If there was only a single copy of them, strange things would happen. Also, if the file was opened twice (to the same fd), what should happen when it's closes? There could be another layer of reference counting to decide when to *really* close the file, but that wouldn't help with the other problems.

---

2) Depends on your code. A smart language (i.e. not C), might refcount the variable holding the open file, and close it just before you reopen the file. Hard to say without seeing the code.

But a little test, opening the same file twice to the same variable in Perl results in the same FD number:

```
perl -e 'open F, "test.txt"; printf "%d ", fileno(F); open F, "test.txt"; printf "%d\n", fileno(F)'
3 3
```

Running it in `strace` shows that the file is closed immediately before the reopen.

With two different variables we get two FD numbers:

```
perl -e 'open F, "test.txt"; printf "%d ", fileno(F); open G, "test.txt"; printf "%d\n", fileno(G)'
3 4
```

---

3) Technically, you could say that the standard file numbers are a convention. A convention codified in [POSIX and the ISO C standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html):

> At program start-up, three streams shall be predefined and need not be opened explicitly: standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output).

But a convention anyway in that it may be possible to run a program without them, without the kernel minding. Or it may not: reading the specification for the `exec` calls, it seems to be [allowed for an implementation to open something for you](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html):

> If file descriptor 0, 1, or 2 would otherwise be closed after a successful call to one of the exec family of functions, implementations may open an unspecified file for the file descriptor in the new process image.

(You can of course close them in the program itself.)

If you arrange to not have them at startup, compatibility is thrown out the door:

> If a standard utility or a conforming application is executed with file descriptor 0 not open for reading or with file descriptor 1 or 2 not open for writing, the environment in which the utility or application is executed shall be deemed non-conforming, and consequently the utility or application might not behave as described in this standard.

The [Linux man pages put it somewhat practically](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html):

> As a general
>             principle, no portable program, whether privileged or not, can
>             assume that these three file descriptors will remain closed across
>             an execve().